# Временное хранилище в pyhon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

*Можно ли сделать временное хранилище для телеграмм бота из переменной, в которой находится json файл и при использование одного словаря (факта) удалять его, и как вообще это сделать если нет ключа у каждого факта???*

*вид json-файла:*[image: json-file]

*код бота:*

```py
import json
import time
from random import choice

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor
from settings import token
from update_data import get_data


bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)

#keybord
next_fact = InlineKeyboardButton('⏭️ Следующий ⏭️', callback_data='Next')
starting_fact = InlineKeyboardButton(' Запуск ', callback_data='Next')
update_fact = InlineKeyboardButton(' Обновление фактов ', callback_data='Update')

fact_next = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(next_fact)
fact_start = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(starting_fact, update_fact)


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def starting(message: types.Message):
    msg = await message.reply(f'<b>Привет, {message.chat.full_name}!</b>', parse_mode='html')
    time.sleep(2)
    await bot.edit_message_text(
        text='<b><i>Хотите запустить бота?</i></b>', 
        chat_id=message.chat.id, 
        message_id=msg.message_id, 
        parse_mode='html', 
        reply_markup=fact_start)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Next')
async def Next(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            fact = choice(data['main']['facts'])
            content = fact['content']
            title = fact['title']
            img = fact['link_img']
    except:
        msg = await bot.send_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            text='<b><i>[Error] Проблема с файлом.</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')  
        time.sleep(4)
        await bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id,
            message_id=msg.message_id,
            text='<b><i>[Restore] Запущен процесс восстановления (~2мин).</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')  
        get_data()
        await bot.delete_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            message_id=msg.message_id,) 

        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            fact = choice(data['main']['facts'])
            content = fact['content']
            title = fact['title']
            img = fact['link_img']

    await bot.send_photo(
        callback_query.from_user.id,
        photo=img,
        caption=f'<b>{title}</b>\n\n<tg-spoiler><i>{content}</i></tg-spoiler>', 
        parse_mode='html',
        reply_markup=fact_next)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Update')
async def Update(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            date = data['times']['date']
            time_json = data['times']['time']
    except:
        msg = await bot.send_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            text='<b><i>[Error] Проблема с файлом.</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')  
        time.sleep(4)
        await bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id,
            message_id=msg.message_id,
            text='<b><i>[Restore] Запущен процесс восстановления (~2мин).</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')  
        get_data()
        await bot.delete_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            message_id=msg.message_id,)
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            date = data['times']['date']
            time_json = data['times']['time']

    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
        text=f'<b><i>Последнее обновление фактов: {date} {time_json} (GMT +05:00).</i></b>', 
        parse_mode='html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
```

*код обновления json-файла:*

```py
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


def get_data():
    page = 0
    url_main = 'https://facts.museum'
    update = True
    headers = {'user-agent': UserAgent().random}
    data = {'main': {'facts': {}}, 'times': {}}
    main_facts = []
    times_date = {}

    try:
        r = requests.get(url=url_main, headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
        title_site = soup.find('div', class_='col-lg mb-3 p-0').find('img').get('alt')

        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data_main = json.load(file)
            title = data_main['main']['facts'][0]['title']
            if title_site == title and data_main['times']['time'] != None and data_main['times']['date'] != None:
                update = False
    except:
        pass

    if update:
        while True:
            url = f'{url_main}/from{page}'
            r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
            blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg mb-3 p-0')

            try:
                if blocks == []:
                    break
                for element in blocks:
                    content = element.find('p', class_='content').text
                    title = element.find('img').get('alt')
                    link_img = element.find('img').get('src')
                    main_facts.append(
                        {
                            'content': content,
                            'title': title,
                            'link_img': f'{url_main}{link_img}'
                        }
                    )
            except:
                break
                
            page += 10

        dt = datetime.now()
        month = dt.month
        day = dt.day
        hour = dt.hour
        minute = dt.minute
        second = dt.second

        if len(str(dt.month)) == 1:
            month = f'0{dt.month}'
        elif len(str(dt.day)) == 1:
            day = f'0{dt.day}'
        elif len(str(dt.hour)) == 1:
            hour = f'0{dt.hour}'
        elif len(str(dt.minute)) == 1:
            minute = f'0{dt.minute}'
        elif len(str(dt.second)) == 1:
            second = f'0{dt.second}'

        date = f'{dt.year}-{month}-{day}'
        time = f'{hour}:{minute}:{second}'
        times_date['date']=date
        times_date['time']=time

        with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data['main']['facts']=main_facts
            data['times']=times_date
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


def main():
    while True:
        get_data()
        time_ = 12 * 3600
        time.sleep(time_)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: выкладывайте код а не скрин

Comment: Изменил, выложил код самого бота, а также код функции, которая обновляет json-файл.

Comment: Нет ключа? Ну добавьте ключ, сгенерите случайный уникальный.

Comment: там почти 4000 словарей лежит, какой я могу уникальный ключ такой сделать для каждого? причем и так уже пытался это сделать - не получилось, пошел сюда

Comment: Добавьте к каждой записи `GUID`: `import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())`. Они генерируются уникальными, вам их хватит на любое количество записей.

Comment: сделал список, в котором словарь, а в этом словаре много уникальных ключей со словарями, как мне получить это значение в боте, если они уникальные? [link json-img](https://ibb.co/Fnm02Kf)